# Defining a function by coordinates of points and degree of a polynomial

Tags: function-construction, interpolation

I'm studying about solid of revolution.

In these studies, I learned that to get the volume of such a solid, I need to know $f(x)$ to describe the contour of the profile. This concept I understood.

$V=\int_a^b \pi  f(x)^2 \, dx$

[image: Imagem]

I already know $f(x)$ I can develop what I need:

[image]

$\begin{align}
\displaystyle 
V=\int^{h}_{0}\pi(\frac{r}{h}x)^2\,dx \\
=\pi\frac{r^2}{h^2}\int^{h}_{0}x^2\,dx \\
=\pi\frac{r^2}{h^2}\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg\vert^h_0 \\
=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h
\end{align}$

```
f[x_] := r/h x;
Integrate[Pi*f[x]^2, {x, 0, h}]
```

> $\frac{1}{3} \pi  h r^2$

$V(r,h)=\frac{1}{3} \pi  h r^2$

The above equation is the $V(r,h)$ function for any type of cone.

The question is:

**How do I proceed to get $f(x)$?**

I made the following attempts...

```
Fit[{{a, b}, {h, r}}, {1, x}, x]

FindFormula[{{0, 0}, {h, r}}, x]
```

I want to get $f(x)$ from the following parameters:

**1** - Enter a list of points

**2** - I want to define the degree of $f(x)$. If the output is of degree $1, 2, ..., n$.

I have already tried `Solve`,`Rsolve`, but I believe that these functions do not accept as input some kind of list of points ...

Comment: Perhaps [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html.en) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want.  You seem to be asking how to use Mathematica to find the function $f(x)$ for a cone, but you already have that function.  Is there a more general case you want to solve?  If so, what is it?

Comment: In the above example I know that $f(x)$ for a cone is $\frac{r}{h}x$. Because I read the theory on another site. But I wanted to get it through some combination of interpolation and some solve ...